# Idea Intellij deleted all my files in src/main IIIII

Tags: java, intellij-idea

[image]

I don't know how it happened, I certainly didn't ask it to nor did I confirm it. Maybe a shortcut? Now I can't find files in file system or busket.

In VCS -> Local History -> Show History, I see this:

[image]

what should I click there to restore files?

I tried clicking Revert but it gives this:
[image]

Comment: This is why backups are so important. When I was just starting out in programming on my first paid job (for University of Delaware, on an Apple II) I lost several weeks work when the only disk the file was on went bad. I was able to recover my work quickly, but it is a lesson I remember even today. Files get deleted, disks go bad, computers get stolen. If these files are important to you, then you need to have a backup plan.

Comment: @NomadMaker That's why making normal IDE that doesn't delete all files out of the blue is important! This is not normal.

Comment: I agree. I'm assuming that this is some sort of bug or an odd feature that caused the problem. However, the IDE doesn't care about your work, only you do. It doesn't matter why the files were lost, only how to recover them. If you've got a boatload of money and time you can use a disk recovery service, which might work. But, if you have a backup, you'd be programming again in very little time.

Comment: @NomadMaker If you have little to say on the subject, why comment? I'm not asking for obvious statements, I asked how to get Idea to bring files back

Comment: [This](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206280449-Recover-project-via-Local-history) may help you. Finding out what event corresponded with that "external change" message may lead to the root of your problem.

Comment: @MarsAtomic Thanks for suggestion, I think I got it fixed with anyther guide on the same site. The accidents date back to 2017 and most recent message is from August 2019. For such a popular IDE it's insane it still happens. I pity any person who would have to go through this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with IntelliJ IDEA, you are keeping your project inside Tomcat `webapps` directory, when the server un-deploys the app, it removes all the files for this app from the deployment location.

Tomcat has removed your files and you blame the IDE for that instead. Never keep your projects under `webapps`!

Comment: You are right. Turned out a .war file I was deploying had the same name as my project folder which I assume led to file replacements/deletes. Entirely my fault, good that Idea helped me recover the files from Local History.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206877445-Please-help-IntelliJ-11-just-deleted-all-my-files-?page=2#comments and someone suggested to use https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk which I downloaded and followed this https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk:_undelete_file_for_FAT. The program itself seems to have frozen on file undelete, but after a while of me not touching it or Idea, files reapperared in Idea and the log appeared in the Local History:

[image]

I don't know for sure if it was connected with TestDisk or with something I clicked in Idea while trying revert things (like that Revert button, though it seemed to have always resulted in the error from the post), but I managed to copypaste files elsewhere.

Hopefully this experience will help someone else to prevent/fix this thing. I had a file delete happen to me a year ago due to some bug linked to deploying files on Tomcat, but I wrote if off as a one-time thing.

After this, however, I'll make sure to tell about my experience any Java dev that I know. Idea can't be trusted with your files, folks!

PS Turned out it all was my fault for putting project folder into `tomcat/webapps`. Never do that! Tomcat kills your files, wipes them so clean that no traces can be found. If it happened to you, go to Idea's Local History ASAP, because after a while you might not see and restore your changes anymore.

Comment: The problem is not with IntelliJ IDEA, you are keeping your project inside Tomcat `webapps` directory, when the server undeploys the app, it removes all the files for this app from the deployment location. So Tomcat has removed your files and you blame the IDE for that instead. Never keep your projects under `webapps` directory!